# Typescript Map throwing error while using its functions (mapobject.keys() is not a function)

Tags: angular, dictionary, typescript, es5-shim

I am a new bee in typescript , In my angular4 project I am receiving a map object as a json.

so I declared a class that is given bellow

```
 <importing... required classes here..>
  export class FormConfig  {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public fieldMap :Map<string,Array<Field>>;
    public fieldList : Array<Field> ;
  }
```

I am receiving exactly same JSON from api. I consoled the object of FormConfig and I am getting the console without any error. My code got compiled without any warning and error. But I can't access the keys and values from the map by using Map's inbuilt functions like forEach,keys,get etc. But IDE showing these function suggestions. Part of my code is given bellow.

```
 formConfig : FormConfig; 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(formConfig)); // works fine

 keys : string [] = Array.from (formConfig.keys()) ; // showing error (formConfig.keys is not a function)
```

I am using es5 target for my angular4 project and the IDE is visual studio code.

Is anybody faced this issue before let me know the mistake I have made here.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are not using `keys` on the right way `Object.keys(obj)`, obj
The object of which the enumerable own properties are to be returned.

Comment: I tried foreach , that is  also not working

Comment: Did you try `keys : string [] = Object.keys(formConfig)` ?

Comment: Yes your code works. Thank you very much , I want to get the value also

Comment: Does typescript support Map ?

Comment: What you want to get? Array of keys and another array of the values?

Comment: I just want keys array and the values array, I just wanna get value by using key

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the values using key like this:

```js
for (const key in formConfig) {
  console.log('The value for ' + key + ' is = ' + formConfig[key]);
}
```

And getting array of the Object's key values is done like this:

```js
keys: string [] = Object.keys(formConfig);
```

Comment: Thank you very much man.. but why this get, foreach and keys function not working ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: If you want to use `foreach`you have to have map `Map.prototype.forEach()`, but in your case it's `Object` and for that you use for .. in

Answer (score 0):

The `keys()` method from the `Object` class can be used instead of writing the a manual for loop.

```
keys: string[] = Object.keys(formConfig);
```