# get the values of specified key of a map typescript ERROR TypeError: this.trmap.get is not a function

Tags: typescript, dictionary, ionic-framework

Hello everyone i should mention that i am new to typescript. Actually i have a map that has numbers as keys and an array of numbers as values. In my html i have to display all the keys and based on the choice made, i have to display the values (both of keys and values are shown as ion-segment-button). The problem is that i can't get the values of any key using `trmap.get(key)`
[here is the error i get in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC1kf.png)///////////////////
[here is the map a par of the json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsGld.png)

This is my ts file:

```js
    trmap: Map<number,number[]>
    values:number[]    

    getSelectedKey(key :number) {
      console.log(key)
      this. values=this.trmap.get(key)
    }
```

Comment: could you provide what errors etc.  you are getting when you try to get the values?

Comment: i made an update showing the error in console..thank u

Comment: I see now, it seems that `get` is defined but not a function. You sure that what you have is indeed a `Map`?

Comment: @alexortizl absolutely as i mentionned i already displayed the keys  in buttons using "*ngFor="let t of trmap | keyvalue"  and i need to display the values of every chosen key i made another update to show u a part of my json in wich u can see that its a map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that there is no need to use trmap.get(key)

as its mentionned in this post [Typescript Map throwing error while using its functions (mapobject.keys() is not a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235007/typescript-map-throwing-error-while-using-its-functions-mapobject-keys-is-not)

values=trmap[key]

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialized to new Map() , because of which you are not able to use its function.

you might find your answer in the below working code.

```
class MapTest{

public trmap: Map<number,number[]>  =  new Map<number,number[]>().set(1,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);
public values:number[] = [];    

  public getSelectedKey(key :number) {
    console.log(key);
    this.values = this.trmap.get(key) as number[];
    return this.values;
   }

}

const test = new MapTest();
console.log(test.getSelectedKey(1));
```

Comment: thank u for ur time and help but the trmap's data is loaded form an api  service call and not some static data.. I changed the declaration of the map to trmap= new Map<number,number[]>() but i still getting the same error